# Python Pandas dataframe how to add an integer to each element in a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

If I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
d = {'id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2.0, 3: 3},
 'lst': {0: [1, 2], 1: [0], 2: [1, 2, 3], 3: np.nan}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

    id        lst
0  0.0     [1, 2]
1  1.0        [0]
2  2.0  [1, 2, 3]
3  3.0        NaN
```

How can I add 1 to each element of the lists, Nan will remain to be Nan. So the output should be like this:

```
    id        lst
0  0.0     [2, 3]
1  1.0        [1]
2  2.0  [2, 3, 4]
3  3.0        NaN
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, try mapping to numpy array and add 1 else you can use apply and add 1:

```
df['lst'] = df['lst'].map(np.array).add(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map()` with `list comprehensions` and `na_action` parameter

```
df['lst'].map(lambda x: [i+1 for i in x],na_action='ignore')
```

Output:

```
0       [2, 3]
1          [1]
2    [2, 3, 4]
3          NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a classical list comprehension:

```
df['lst'] = [[x+1 for x in l] if isinstance(l, list) else l
             for l in df['lst']]
```

Output:

```
    id        lst
0  0.0     [2, 3]
1  1.0        [1]
2  2.0  [2, 3, 4]
3  3.0        NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to convert the nested list column to an [AwkwardDtype](https://awkward-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), and subsequently apply vectorized operations on the column:

```py
# pip install awkward-pandas
import awkward-pandas as akpd

In [61]: df.astype({"lst":akpd.AwkwardDtype()}).assign(lst = lambda f: f.lst + 1)
Out[61]: 
    id        lst
0  0.0     [2, 3]
1  1.0        [1]
2  2.0  [2, 3, 4]
3  3.0        NaN
```

For this however, you can just use @anky's solution, since there isnt much complexity to the nested list.

Comment: You always have nice lib suggestions ;)